# Deleting blobs is too slow

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I am looking for a way to delete blobs in azure container.
I've tried deleting the blobs from the azure library, but it's too slow.

There are expected to be around 1 million files that need to be deleted every day. Must be run through hangfire. I tried azcopy and locally it works and deletes them very quickly, but when I upload it as an azure web app it doesn't delete the files.

I have `azcopy.exe` set to copy always and it is in azure web app but it doesn't delete anything. Is there any option to delete these files quickly or somehow to run azcopy through hangfire?.

```cs
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Config.StorageConnStr);
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(StorageConnection);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ExportContainerName);
CloudBlobDirectory folder = container.GetDirectoryReference(jobid.ToLower());
var blobs = folder.ListBlobs();

foreach (var blob in blobs)
{
    ((CloudBlob)blob).DeleteIfExists();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use `BlobBatch.DeleteBlob` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbatch.deleteblob?view=azure-dotnet for bulk deletions.  Your current code is running synchronously in serial which is your bottleneck.  Note this marks things for deletion via garbage collection so may take a minute or so to actually take effect.

It could work something like this

```
BlobBatch batch = blobClient.GetBlobBatch();

foreach (var blob in blobs) {
    DeleteBlobOptions options = new DeleteBlobOptions()
    {
        DeleteSnapshotsOption = DeleteSnapshotsOption.None
    };
    AccessCondition accessCondition = AccessCondition.GenerateIfExistsCondition();
    batch.DeleteBlob(containerName, blob.Name, accessCondition, options, null);
}

await blobClient.SubmitBatchAsync(batch);
```